# Scroll doesn't work with ScrollView and absolute positioned component

Tags: react-native

I have a scrollView and a component with absolute position. The scrollView doesn't scroll at all. Have a look at the code: https://snack.expo.io/@codebyte99/overlap-test

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
            source={{
              uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png',
              cache: 'only-if-cached',
            }}
            style={{width: 400, height: 100}}
          />

        <View style={styles.overlap}>
            <Text>Event1</Text>
            <Text>Event2</Text>
            <Text>Event3</Text>
            <Text>Event4</Text>
            <Text>Event5</Text>
            <Text>Event6</Text>
            <Text>Event7</Text>

            <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'orange', height: 800, width: 500 }}/>
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', height: 800, width: 500 }}/>
        </View>
    </View>
</ScrollView>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  overlap: {
    width: 300, 
    backgroundColor: 'red', 
    borderColor: 'red', 
    borderWidth: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 80,
    zIndex: 9999,
    overflow: 'visible'
  },
});
```

If the flex is not used in scrollView, the absolute positioned component are not visible completely and if it is used, the scroll doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `flex: 1`, the ScrollView container takes all available space, however this does not include the items positioned absolutely inside it since they are out of the document flow.

So you should remove it, and instead you should give the `container` style enough height to display every item inside:

```js
container: {
  flex: 0,
  alignItems: 'center',
  paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  padding: 8,
  height: 2000,
},
```

Comment: setting height might not be a good idea. If the component height is less than 2000(as in above eg), then there will be white space at the end of the screen.

Comment: You are explicitly making an item out of the document flow but still asking for its dimensions to be considered when positioning other items. It seems a bit contradictory to me.
Maybe you don't need `position: absolute` after all. What about something like this? https://snack.expo.io/@remeus/relative-overlap

Comment: I was using Svg with position: absolute this helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to change `flex: 1` to `flexGrow: 1` in `contentContainerStyle`.